# associate an element of a (3d) array with an image that is displayed by a label in the content pane (java swing GUI)

Tags: java, arrays, swing, oop, game-development

I'm creating a solitaire game using java swing gui. I'm trying to make this whole program very object-oriented. I've just learned java, but since it's my first language, I wasn't taught OOP and how to implement it into my code design (although I'm trying to learn this myself, as java is an object-oriented language).

I've created a 3d array within the constructor (but I'm not sure if I should put this in a separate method that is designated for the initial game state (which is alike for how the game has to be successfully completed)) for the card suit, colour, and value.

I want to either associate a value to a
each card in the deck between the image and the array, or be able to have an image be directly associated with an array so it's possible for the program to know the correct and legal sequencing in the gameplay.

all the cards require a back and front facing card so either is displayed depending on position & game state.

(unrelated, but I'm also making a layered pane for the depth of each card which will be important for game state)

i've previously learned how to display images in java with swing using `imageIcon` and attaching them to buttons or labels. I'm not sure if using `imageIO` would be better. Maybe a 3d array isn't the right choice? Any guidance/help is greatly appreciated. Thank you :)

the 3d array looks like this

```
String [][][] deck = new String[13][2][2]; //only 2 elements for suits in each colour, out of 4 suits
        String[] numbers = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
        String[] colors = {"Red", "Black"}; //z
        String[] suits = {"Spade", "Club", "Heart", "Diamond"}; //y

        }
        for (int n = 0; n < 13; n++) {     //start with value -> colour -> suit
            for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++) { 
            for (int s = 0; s < 2; s++) {  
                if (c == 0) {              //if c==0 then suit != 1 or 2
                deck[n][c][s] = colors[c] + " " + numbers[n] + " of " + suits[s + 2];
                                           //bc adding 2 makes y be [2] or [4] bc those suits are red //combines array to form y@x in each z
                } else {
                deck[n][c][s] = colors[c] + " " + numbers[n] + " of " + suits[s]; 
// black card ==1 and it c==1, you wont add 2 to the value of [s], so black can only be [0] or [1] (spade and club)
                }
            }
            }
        }
```

little bit of info about some of my ideas for how the game will be organized:

the game will roughly look like this.

The circle "1" is where the unshuffled deck/array will start (initial gamestate), and this is also what it will look like when the player successfully solves the game (initial gamestate==final gamestate) so each suit has a designated start and finish position.

the array (the deck) will be shuffled by using Donald Knuth's shuffling algorithm.

after multiple iterations of shuffling, I'll divide the cards (elements in the array) into 2 piles: the hand pile (24 cards not yet played), the tableau pile (where the player plays to place the cards in sequential order of high-low and black/red or red/black)

this part is important-

when the player taps a button or label of a cards image, a MouseListener is used to get the position where it was clicked, the program searches for which card value & colour occupies that position, and then the program will look for legal moves that are available for the player.

Comment: Step back for a second. Solitaire is made up of a deck of cards, each card has a suit and number associated with it - start by making a `Card` class, which has a `Suit` and `Value` property. This forms the bases of your "model". All you game logic should be based around a `Deck` of `Card`s. You then should have some kind of rendering system which given a `Card` can render an appropriate image (ie a class based off a `JPanel` with a `Card` property).  So, now when the `CardPane` is clicked, you know which `Card` it represents and this can be feed into the "game engine"

Comment: Also note that a playing card program is often used to teach [Java enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/enums.html) and is considered a classic use-case for this.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you so much for replying! I'll make a card class, but are you saying that the suit and value should instance variable of the card class, or subclasses of card? and with the part about JPanel, do you think that the JPanel extends the card class or the other way around? should the 3d array be discarded completely or maybe make it into an array list inside the card class or inside a subclass that handles shuffling?

Comment: `Card` has properties.  You can't extend from `Card` AND `JPanel`, that's not how inheritance works in Java.  Instead, you should have a `CardPane` (or card view, what ever) which has a `Card` property.  I personally wouldn't bother with the arrays, instead you should have three containers of cards (back by a `List` as it's easier to manage), this all begins to form the back bone of your core data model

Comment: aw shucks. I know very little about enums b/c I couldn't understand how to use them through my readings when I was considering implementing them into my program. Before I read more about them, do you know if they could be useful in solving my card image handling problem? @HovercraftFullOfEels (thank you very much for this piece of info btw)

Comment: emikyriberts: I use them less for the GUI-specific aspect of my programs, for the "view", but I use them quite a bit for the program's non-GUI business logic, the "model", which is exactly what @MadProgrammer has been discussing above: the separation of your GUI concerns from the underlying program logic concerns.

Comment: Thank you for your responses @MadProgrammer ! What do you specifically mean by properties? Are you referring to class attributes, objects, or object behaviors? What do you mean by containers? And by lists, are you talking about array lists or something else?

Comment: @emikyriberts Class attributes (properties of an object).  A "containers" is a general term for something which "contains" other things.  I might not use a `List` directly to manage the cards for example, but a "container" class which acts as the interface/API and exposes "logic" (ie `popCard`), that way you can inject logic into the process depending on you what you want to do.  And, yes `List` is an interface, which `ArrayList` implements, but you should be focused on "coding to interface not implementation", so you expose `List` to the outside world and internally, we don't care

Comment: @emikyriberts And `enum`s are super powerful and super confusing at times, especially if you've coded in other languages (and don't even get me started with Swift `enum`s ).  But essentially, they are a super great way to constrain the range of values a property might have - much better then `String`s!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it object oriented you should probably make a class called Card with fields number, color and suit. Don't forget to have separation of concerns. Separate the presentation layer from the business layer. If you end up writing code for which you can't even tell what's front end code and what's back end code then that's bad. Your front end can have a CardDisplayer class, which is an adapter class to the Card class. CardDisplayer takes in a Card and it draws it on the screen.
Your front end sends messages to the back end when the player makes a move. Your back end should not make any changes to the data that front end has. Your back end should message back the front end with legal moves or with the new state of the game.
You also need a game loop. When the game finishes the player should go back to some sort of a start menu.